# Erro Dapper Framework: Could not load file or assembly 'Dapper, A strongly-named assembly is required

Tags: c#, dapper

Olá,

Eu utilizo Dapper Framework para realizar minhas consultas SQL em C# Windows Forms, e recentemente iniciei um novo projeto, e me deparei com este erro:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Dapper, Version=1.50.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)

Alguém poderia recomendar algum tipo de procedimento?! Já tentei reinstalar o dapper e o erro persiste ... Procurei em alguns sites e pediam para fazer alguns procedimentos através do console do visual studio e nenhum resolveu o meu problema, help-me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tentou instalar o PM (**Package Manager Console**) > `Install-Package Dapper.StrongName`?

Referência:  [Dapper dot net (strong named) 1.50.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.StrongName/)

[Post gingo muito bom sobre.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197133/anything-wrong-with-not-signing-a-net-assembly)